# WPF Context menu on TabControl header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` and have bound its `ItemSource` to a `ObserverableCollection` of view models. I have also set its `DataTemplate` to the view assioated with the view model.

This works fine and in `ItemContainerStyle` I added a `ContextMenu` that have a `MenuItem`. How do I get the `MenuItems` click event to fire in my code? I am not able to pick up the event in `Delete_OnClick`. Also the sender should be a reference to the view model that is bound to the `ItemSource` of the `TabControl`.

```
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyTabItems}">

        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MyTabItemViewModel}">
                <views:MyTabItem/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>

        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="Delete_OnClick"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    </TabControl>


    // In code behind I have this method that should be triggered when the
    // Delete MenuItem is clicked
    private void Delete_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabItem = (ITabItem) sender;
        ViewModel.DeleteTab(tabItem);
    }
```

Summary: I can right click on the tab header and click on Delete but I do not get any events from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my original answer considerably.

My understanding is that you use MVVM pattern. If so you shouldn't use event handlers directly. Instead you should bind a menu item to a command.

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command={Binding MyCommand} />
</ContextMenu>
```

`MyCommand` should be a property defined in your `MyTabItemViewModel` class.

```
public class MyTabItemViewModel 
{
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

`MyCommand` property can return an instance of any class that implements [ICommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. It can be a predefined command (for example see [ApplicationCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands(v=vs.110).aspx) class) or your own.  Here is an example how your `DeleteCommand` could look like:

```
public class DeleteCommand: ICommand
{
    private ParentVM Parent { get; set; }
    private MyTabItemViewModel Item { get; set; }

    public MyCustomCommand (ParentVM parent, MyTabItemViewModel item)
    {
        Parent= parent;
        Item = item;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        parent.RemoveItem(item);
    }

    ...
}
```

I assumed that your view model with the `MyTabItems` collection is called `ParentVM` and that it has a public method `RemoveItem` which is responsible for removing a given item from this collection.

You can instantiate `DeleteCommand` in the constructor of `MyTabItemViewModel`. For example:

```
public class MyTabItemViewModel 
{
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    public MyTabItemViewModel(ParentVM parent)
    {
        MyCommand = new DeleteCommand(parent, this);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Where do I use MyCustomCommand? And is it not the view model that have the collection of TabItems job to remove a tabItem? The tabitem can not remove itself from the collection. (Well this is in the case I want to press on Delete and remove a tabItem)

Comment: Yes, I use a MVVM model :)

Answer (score 2):

Use an EventSetter instead, that should work in your case

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete" >
                                <MenuItem.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Delete_OnClick"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </MenuItem.Style>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
```

Comment: Thanks, It did. And I can cast the sender of `Delete_OnClick` to a MenuItem which DataContext is the viewmodel of the tabItem. I will just look a bit more into Michaels solution before accepting an answer.